# "USBSerial" has no member "printf" on STM32F411CEU6 in PlatformIO / ststm32

Tags: c++, usbserial, mbed, stm32f4, platformio

Trying to run [this USB Serial example](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v6.4/apis/usbserial.html) (bottom) to learn MBED, but I get the following compilation error:

```
class "USBSerial" has no member "printf"
```

Is it possible it isn't implemented for the STM32F411? Or is this a problem with MBED itself?
Seems like this should be basic functionality. Not finding much useful info on google when searching for this error. Has anyone else seen this error before?

potentially useful details:

IDE: vscode/platformIO

platformio.ini:

```
[env:nucleo f411re]
platform = ststm32
framework = mbed
board = nucleo_f411re
monitor_speed = 115200
```

MBED version: 6.2 (as I recall from memory, though I doubt it matters since I checked the docs for a few versions and the API and example appears unchanged)

Answer (score 0):

The method `printf()` (which is a C, not C++ concept anyway) does not exist, simple as that. Use `sprintf()` if that's what you're familar with, then [`USBSerial.write()`](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v6.4/mbed-os-api-doxy/class_u_s_b_serial.html#a2b295c28246c7c03393a40050313d4c2), perhaps.

Comment: Sure, I get that. But I've used printf in C++ programs before without any fuss. C++ is supposed to be (mostly) backwards compatible with C, right? Also the official documentation for MBED uses printf as the example. The write function is not a drop-in replacement.

Comment: There's no `printf` in C++ standard streams either; however, `USBSerial` doesn't seem to have `operator<<`, which is perhaps more of an oversight/omission.

Comment: That's a good point, I agree I think this might have been an ommision/oversight since it does clearly say on the bufferedSerial API reference at the very bottom "We recommend you use the standard C I/O library directly to print to the console in Mbed OS" Probably should file a bug report for this.